# Where is function overriding done?

Tags: c++, python, ruby, overloading, overriding

Where in the process of creating the program, compiler, linker etc., is the overriding of functions and operator overloading done?

I'm particularly interested where it is done in C++, Ruby and Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function **overloading** is (at least in C++) handled internally inside the compiler.  The idea is that the code that the compiler ultimately generates will be hardcoded to call the appropriate function, as if the functions all had different names and you called the function uniquely suited to the arguments.  More generally, in *most* compiled languages that support overloading, the overload resolution is done at compile-time and the emitted code will always call the indicated function.  For example, Haskell supports compile-time overloading this way.

Operator overloading is a special case of general overloading, so it's usually handled the same way.

Function **overriding** (a term that arises in OOP when a derived class inherits from a base class and redefines one of its methods) is almost always resolved at runtime, since a compiler can't always tell which function is going to be invoked without actually knowing about the types at runtime.  Some compilers might be able to statically prove that a certain object has a specific type and can then optimize the dynamic dispatch away, but it's impossible to do this in all cases.

I am not aware of any dynamic languages that support overloading, since in theory you could introduce new overload candidates as the program was running.  I would love to be enlightened if such a language exists.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "overriding". AIUI, a non-virtual function can be overridden, but the function called is determined at compile time. You can probably also do fun things like `virtual void operator()();`...

Comment: @tc- A non-virtual function in C++ can be **overloaded** but not **overridden**.  Trying to override a non-virtual function just introduces an overload in the derived class.

Comment: @tc.: Nope.  Non-virtual functions are hidden, not overridden.

Comment: I think you could count multimethods in clojure as kind of overloading. At least you can dispatch based on the type of each parameter.

Comment: @DaVinci- My understanding is that the dispatch is done dynamically rather than statically based on the types of the arguments.  By my understanding, overloading differs from overriding in that overloading is dispatched based on the *static* type of the arguments, whereas overriding is dispatched based on the *dynamic* types of the arguments.  Is this correct?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Really interesting...is there ever a time in which the compiler would take care of a function I inherited and then overrode (e.g., overriding a virtual function in C++)?

Comment: I don't know of any compilers that actually do global analysis to predict where virtual functions should be dispatched, though there probably are a few out there.  In theory it can definitely be done in limited cases, and the compilers research community definitely knows how to do it for a couple of cases.

Comment: @Oboto inherited virtual functions for a class go through a v-table that each class possess for function look-up.  If class `A` had a function like `virtual void run();` and class `B` inherited from class `A`, and also had another function called `virtual void run()`, then when calling `run()` on an instance of either class, a run-time lookup in that class's v-table determines which function, either `A::run` or `B::run` will be executed.  This is what makes class polymorphism possible.

Comment: @Jason Ah that makes sense now! Thanks for the explanation. Would you happen to have any links to articles or posts about this? It sounds interesting and I'd like to understand it more.

Comment: @Oboto here is a good link to get you started: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-functions.html

Answer (score 3):

For C++, operator overloading is done at the compiler level though a name-mangling process that creates a unique name identifier for every function so that the linker will not complain about duplicate function definitions.  In C++, operator overloading is possible because overloadable operations like `+`, `-`, `*`, etc. are actual functions themselves that have the prefix `operator` followed by the symbol of the operation. So for instance, an overloaded `operator+` function with a function signature like

```
my_type operator+(const my_type& lhs, const my_type& rhs);
```

will not conflict with another `operator+` function with a different signature, even though both functions have the same `operator+` name, because each version of the function will have a different name at the assembly-language level after the C++ compiler's name-mangling process is complete.  Name-mangling has another benefit in that allows C and C++ compiled code to be used with the same linker, since two functions with the same name will not exist and cause a linker error.

Note that in C, that even if you create two functions with different signatures, if they have the same name, since the C-compiler will not do any name-mangling, the linker will complain about duplicate definitions of the function.

Comment: Downvoter: What's wrong with this answer?  It seems perfectly reasonable.

Comment: @templatetypedef I assume it's because the question is about overriding and *operator* overloading, not overloading in the general case.

Comment: Okay, I've edited to make it specific to operator overaloading ... it's still the same process as function overloading though ...

Answer (score 0):

Python is not linked/compiled, it is interpreted.
So, the normal overriding is done when class sources are parsed. Of course, due to dynamic nature you can always override during the runtime as well.
I suppose that alternate implementations using the byto-code compilation do it on the compile-time.

I also think the above is true for Ruby as well.